# Animation Clip rotates model in unexpected way

Tags: unity, animation

I have 2 animation clips.
In the following animation preview, the same model is being used for both clips.

As you can see in the Animation window dopesheet, there is no significant rotation difference.
However, one animation clip rotates the model 90 degrees to the left.

I have inspected all the rotation values in the animation tab. I just don't see any difference.

What causes this significant rotation difference?

[image: Animation Clip 1]

[image: Animation Clip 2]

Answer (score 1):

I got it.
The rotation was due to a rotation in the "hip" bone (y was -70).

I didn't take a look at that one as it was so much down low in the hierarchy.
But being the root of my model, it makes sense.

I zero-ed it out, and now both animations face approximately the same direction.